# Java: What's the value of a hidden superclass field when called using super?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

Consider the following example:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Maruti().howManyTires());
        new Maruti().getColor();
    }
}
```

```
class Car {
    private int tires = 1;

    public int howManyTires(){
        return tires; 
    }

    public void getColor(){
        getNiceColour();
    }

    public void getNiceColour(){
        System.out.println("Blue");
    }
}
```

```
class Maruti extends Car {

    private int tires = 10;

    public int howManyTires(){
        return super.howManyTires();
    }

    public void getColor(){
        super.getColor();
    }

    public void getNiceColour(){
        System.out.println("Magenta");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1
Magenta
```

My question is that when the superclass' `howManyTires` function is called through `super`, the `this` reference is clearly of the subclass (as show by the call to the `getColor` method). Yet, it return the superclass' `tires` field.

I understand that fields are only hidden not overridden, but unless these fields are bound to the class (like a class variable), calling the superclass' `howManyTires` method should have returned the `tires` values bound by the `this` reference (which is of the subclass)

Comment: `this` is **always** a reference to the current class. Without exception. (`this` never refers to the superclass)

Comment: *I understand that fields are only hidden not overridden*: well, apparently, no. If it returned 10, it would mean that the field tires in Maruti overrides the field tires in Car. Fields are resolved statically, at compile time. When the Car class is compiled, the compiler generates byte code for the howManyTires that reads and returns the value of the field Car.tires. Field values are not resolved polymorphically, at runtime.

Comment: @JBNizet The question whose duplicate this is supposed to be, talks about the simple case of fields not being overridden but only duplicated. This question asks why, when the `this` reference of the superclass points to the subclass, does the superclass' `howManyTires` returns the (edit:superclass') `tires` field.

Comment: It does not. It returns 1. 1 is the value of the superclass `tires` field. The simple case of fields not being overridden is the only case there is. Fields are not overridden. Methods can be. Not fields. When the method Car.howManyTires() is **compiled**, the **compile**-time type of `this` is Car. So the value of the field Car.tires is returned.

Comment: That's what i meant, but typed the wrong word. If `this` refers to the subclass, then why is `this.tires` returning superclass' `tires`? Apparently, the answer is that fields depend on the compile-time type of `this` while methods depend on its run-time type. But this isn't obviously apparent from just saying that fields are not overridden but methods are. If the person at the botton hadn't given his answer (and subsequent edits), I wouldn't have understood this. That's why this question shouldn't be marked as duplicate IMO

Comment: @Daud glad you got it. But honestly, this is just the first duplicate I've found. Since I'm on StackOverflow, I must have seen this question asked 50 times already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that fields are only hidden not overridden...

Exactly. There are two `tires` fields in the object created by `new Maruti`, the `tires` field of `Car` and the `tires` field of `Maruti`. Which one you access depends on the type of the reference you use to access the object. The type of `this` is determined by the class the method is in: `this` within a `Maruti` method has the type `Maruti`; `this` within a `Car` method has the type `Car`. That's why `Maruti`'s `howManyTires` accesses the `Maruti` `tires`, and `Car`'s `howManyTires` accesses `Car`'s `tires`, even though in both cases the object `this` refers to is a `Maruti` object.

This may be simpler to see with public fields and more obvious types:

```
class Base {
    public int a = 1;
}

class Sub extends Base {
    public int a = 2;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Sub s = new Sub();
        Base b = s;
        System.out.println(s.a); // 2
        System.out.println(b.a); // 1
    }
}
```

`s` is of type `Sub`, `b` is of type `Base`. They both refer to the same object, but note how the type of the reference used to access the field affects which field is accessed.

This is true of fields and **not** of methods:

```
class Base {
    public int a = 1;
    public int method() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    public int a = 2;
    public int method() {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Sub s = new Sub();
        Base b = s;
        System.out.println(s.a);        // 2
        System.out.println(b.a);        // 1
        System.out.println(s.method()); // 2
        System.out.println(b.method()); // 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate here: the Car.howManyTires() method uses `this`, yet it accesses the Car's tires.

Comment: @JBNizet - True. But the type of `this` within `Car.howManyTires()` is `Car`, right? Even though the object is a `Maruti`, the type of the reference is `Car` which explains why you get `Car`'s `tires`. Or is that explanation a bit off?

Comment: That's indeed the important part, that is missing (IMHO) in your answer. I would even say: the *declared, compile-time* type of `this` within Car.howManyTires() is Car.

Comment: @JBNizet - Okay, I thought I'd said that, but apparently not. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: @JBNizet - Rewriting, I saw what you meant. I want to write "Thanks again!" but, um, I don't seem to have said "thanks" above. :-| Anyway: Thanks!

Comment: Always a pleasure :-)